# How to create a remote branch from an existing remote branch?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

Suppose there are several existing branches on git. I want to create a new branch on it from an existing branch. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you remote named *origin*.

First, you create your branch locally
`git checkout -b branch-name origin/branch-name`

The remote branch is automatically created when you push it to the remote server. So when you feel for it, you can just do
`git push origin branch-name`

Answer (score 0):

To simply create a new branch without checking it out:

```
git branch newbranch existingbranch
```

To check it out and start working on it, you then:

```
git checkout newbranch
```

To accomplish both of the above in one step:

```
git checkout -b newbranch existingbranch
```